# Concatenate Javascript variable inside laravel blade curly braces

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I want to concatenate javascript variable within blade `{{ curly braces }}` as following:

Currently:

`ajax: "{{ route(api.colors) }},"`

What I want:

```
var page='colors';
...
ajax: "{{ route(api."+page+") }},"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can do something like assign a data attribute to one of your HTML elements or a hidden HTML element where you pass the route (unless it contains sensitive information). And then access it in your javascript as a string.

Comment: I do have hidden input, but I want to pass its value dynamically.

Comment: Does the route that you are passing depend on user interaction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do this directly because the curly brackets are rendered on the server and javascript runs on the client side. You could put a placeholder in you route and then replace this part in your javascript code. Like so:

```
// Imagine the `api.page` route value is `/controller/{page}`:
ajax: "{{ route(api.page) }}".replace("{page}", page);
```

Comment: That is a very clever way to do it. +1

Comment: OK, I tried this ajax: "{{ route('api.items') }}".replace("{items}", 'colors') but it's not working, still pointing to old route.

Comment: but does your rendered route contain a string `{items}`?

Comment: @Jerodev Yes, it contains {items}.

Comment: Clear and clever way to do it. There's no doubt. Great, man!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, it worked for me.

```
 var id = $('#user_id').val();
 console.log(id);   
 ajax: "{{ URL::to('/meme') }}/poster/"+id+"",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ziggy library](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy).

It has a helper function `route(route_name)` that you can easily use for this purpose.